# a lot of update (same column) at one query, how to do this dynamic query?

Tags: sql-server-ce

i have  queries as these:

```
update table1 set quantity=(quantity)+3 where productsid=1
update table1 set quantity=(quantity)+4 where productsid=2
update table1 set quantity=(quantity)+5 where productsid=3
update table1 set quantity=(quantity)+6 where productsid=4
update table1 set quantity=(quantity)+1 where productsid=5
update table1 set quantity=(quantity)+3 where productsid=6
update table1 set quantity=(quantity)+2 where productsid=7
```

but i am working on sqlce i couldn't send all queries, and send one for one
take much time, so i need a dynamic query, with it gets a only query with work as these queries. maybe using case?

Comment: What's the logic behind it? I can't find a pattern in here...

Comment: a loop for, getting productsid and value you could see wich is added to quantity

Comment: Only way is to bypass the query processor and use TableDirect and SqlCeUpdateableRecord

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem was solved with 2 query and one loop for

```
string query1 = " UPDATE table1  SET  quantity = CASE productsid  ";
string query_where = "END  WHERE productsid IN ";
```

after a loop for, query is it

```
UPDATE table1  SET  quantity= CASE productsid  
When '1' Then quantity  - 2.0000000000 
When '2' Then quantity  - 2.0000000000 
When '3' Then quantity  - 1.0000000000 
When '4' Then quantity  - 1.0000000000 
When '5' Then quantity  - 1.0000000000 
When '6' Then quantity  - 5.0000000000 
When '7' Then quantity  - 1.0000000000 
When '8' Then quantity  - 1.0000000000 
When '9' Then quantity  - 1.0000000000 
END  WHERE productsid IN 
(  
'1',
'2',
'3',
'4',
'5',
'6',
'7',
'8',
'9'
)
```

and i could use `ExecuteNonQuery();` and its all! only one query..